# P value of Portmanteau Test from VAR model

Tags: r, time-series, var, forecasting

I am working with bivariate time series data. I used VAR model to fit and forecast. 
But the "p" value from seria.test (Portmanteau Test) gives values p<< 0.05. Is that okay?

```
> var1 = VAR(datax.ts, p= 8)
> serial.test(var1, lags.pt=10, type = "PT.asymptotic")

    Portmanteau Test (asymptotic)

data:  Residuals of VAR object var1
Chi-squared = 23.724, df = 8, p-value = 0.002549
```

or Is this wrong? Also the forecast is a flat one. Any idea how to change this?

I have attached Raw [Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7I0DT-PiG4RcFV5Q2xnOUVENmc/view?usp=sharing) for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have estimated a `VAR model` using the package `vars`. You went on and tested the model for `autocorrelation in the errors` using a `portmanteau test`.

> The null hypothesis of no autocorrelation is rejected since the p-value of 0.002549 is lower than the significance level alpha of 0.05.

Since autocorrelation is an undesirable feature you want to move on and search for a model with no autocorrelation.

Rephrased, because you still have autocorrelation in the errors, there is variance that remains which is not explained by the model.